# How ISNULL can affect query performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

I have a query (it is part of bigger complex query) 
`SELECT ISNULL(dbo.Event.Sap_Equipment_ID,0)
FROM dbo.Event`

When I try to execute that, there is no answer, it is running forever. 
But when I remove `ISNULL()` it completes very fast.

Column `Sap_Equipment_ID` is:
Type: bigint 
Length: 19
Not Null: false

What possible reasons could be?

Comment: There's a index over that Id column? That helps explain why it's a lot faster without using that function

Comment: What is the context of this in the larger query? What do the execution plans look like?

Comment: It is where condition for filtering some IDS. I am not sure, that I can share the whole query - sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely (especially since the field ends on `_ID`), the field is indexed.

Using any operations on an indexed field makes the index unusable for the query. That's likely why the time required increases.